# New row-macro inserts at the top instead of the bottom of the range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a button that allows the user to insert a new row at the bottom of a table. My code inserts at the top. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub newRow()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Sheet1.Activate

    'goes to the next empty row at the bottom of the range
    nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1


    'inserts new row 
    Cells(nextRow).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `cells(nextrow,1)` instead. Now it recognises nextrow as a column index instead of a row.

Comment: Please note also you do `.Row + 1` and `.offset(1)` which is a duplicate step down, meaning you go two down from the last row, instead of one (the one after your last row).

Comment: When you say "Table" could you provide the table name as well ? That would help us to write accurate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you access `Cells` with 2 parameters, the parameters mean row and column. But if you access it with only one parameter (as you do for the `Insert`-statement), if counts all cells from left to right and after that from top to bottom. If, for example, `nextRow` is 7, `Cells(nextRow)` will not return the cell at row 7, col 1, it will return the 7th cell which is row 1, col 7.

So, try  `Cells(nextRow, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert` instead, that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this one

```
Sub newRow()
Range("A1").ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
End Sub
```